# Ancestral visa to Netherlands

Tags: netherlands

My grandparents immigrated to SA in the late '40s (after the war). My father is SA born. My mother, born in The Hague 1938, naturalized, but is not sure if she did so before or after my birth.

How and where do I confirm when this happeedn as I, with my husband and son, want to move to The Netherlands?

Comment: If your mother doesn’t have any papers relating to her naturalization, you could seek advice from a lawyer or try contacting the Department of Home Affairs in South Africa http://www.dha.gov.za/index.php/ask-us

Comment: Did your father's parents naturalize before he was born?  Before his 21st birthday?  When were you born?

Comment: My father is of French descendents.... 3 generations SA born.

Comment: Thank you for commenting. Much appreciated. Any ideas on which laywers (SA) would be the best to contact on this as Home Affairs is a route that will just be a maze of unanswered questions. 

Comment: @Cola I can’t recommend a practitioner in SA but I’d think your best approach would be to contact the Legal Practice Council https://www.lssa.org.za/public/getting-legal-assistance/find-a-legal-practitioner

Comment: @Cola This may help you too http://ind.nl/en/dutch-citizenship/Pages/Becoming-a-Dutch-citizen-abroad.aspx